# Prepared statements in Extbase TYPO3 7.6 not working

Tags: php, typo3, prepared-statement, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to submit the query as a prepared statement, like below.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->usePreparedStatement(TRUE);
$sqlParamList[] = 'test@gamil.com';
$sql = 'SELECT uid FROM table_name WHERE email = ?';
$query->statement($sql, $sqlParamList);
$result = $query->execute();
```

But I always get errors like below.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1'

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse your `$sql` to a prepared statement first:

```
$preparedSql = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\PreparedStatement::class, $sql, 'table_name');
```

With `$this->objectManager->get()` you instantiiate the class `PreparedStatement` with the arguments `$sql` and `'table_name'`.

This will change your $sql and parse the `?` to be used as prepared statement.

Comment: can you please explain in details?

Comment: I added some explanation in the answer directly.

Comment: ok fine. but did't understand after where can i used **$preparedSql**  variables. like this:$uqery->statement($preparedSql, $sqlParamList);

Comment: `$preparedSql` is a new variable to show you that the `$sql` is now prepared for prepared statement. :)

Comment: after pass $preparedSql variable in statement() getting empty result.

Comment: can you explain via example in your answers please.

Comment: Here you can see an example (in German): http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2016-April/115826.html

Comment: yes. i will do something like this but getting empty result.

Comment: may be i think this future is removed in typo3 7.6

Comment: I have this class yet in version 8.7. Will be removed in v9, but then the way is with Doctrine DBAL.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->usePreparedStatement(TRUE);
$sqlParamList = [
    ':email' => 'test@gamil.com'
];
$sql = 'SELECT uid FROM table_name WHERE email = :email';
$query->statement($sql, $sqlParamList);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Cannot test it, just an approach.